# Get links form wikipedia

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrape this page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shopping_malls_in_the_United_States

The links are in:

```
data = response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul[9]/li').extract()
```

where data is:

```
[<Selector xpath='//*/li' data=u'<li><a href="/wiki/Ala_Moana_Center" tit'>,
<Selector xpath='//*/li' data=u'<li><a href="/wiki/Kahala_Mall" title="K'>,
<Selector xpath='//*/li' data=u'<li><a href="/wiki/Pearlridge" title="Pe'>,
<Selector xpath='//*/li' data=u'<li><a href="/wiki/Prince_Kuhio_Plaza" t'>,
<Selector xpath='//*/li' data=u'<li><a href="/wiki/Victoria_Ward_Centers'>]
```

The links I need are:

https://en.wikipedia.org + href

for example:

'https://en.wikipedia.org' + '/wiki/Ala_Moana_Center'

for doing this I'm using regex

```
link = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + re.findall('href="([^"]+)',str(data[0]))[0]

name = re.findall('href="([^"]+)',str(data[0]))[0].replace('/wiki/','').replace('_',' ')
```

The issue is that with this approach I'll have to make  a loops to get the links, there is a way to create those links directly form scrapy or atleast in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nono, no need for regexes, point your XPath directly to the `href` attributes:

```
data = response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul[9]/li/a/@href').extract()
```

Then, use [`urlparse.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) to construct absolute URLs using `response.url` as a base:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

base_url = response.url
data = [urljoin(base_url, link) 
        for link in response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul[9]/li/a/@href').extract()]
```

---

As a side note, I don't particularly like the `ul[9]` part in your XPath expression - using indexes is not, generally speaking, reliable and can easily break - and you cannot read and understand the expression. It looks like, you are looking for the Hawaiian shopping malls. Locate the links based on the preceding `Hawaii` label:

```
//a[. = "Hawaii"]/following::ul/li/a/@href
```

With this expression it is easy to see what are you actually locating.

---

Here is how you can group the links by state, example from the Shell:

```
$ scrapy shell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shopping_malls_in_the_United_States
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> base_url = response.url
>>>
>>> data = {}
>>> for state in response.xpath("//h3[span[@class='mw-headline']]"):
...     state_name = state.xpath(".//a[@title]/text()").extract_first()
...     links = [urljoin(base_url, link) for link in state.xpath('./following-sibling::*[1]//li/a/@href').extract()]
...     data[state_name] = links
>>>
>>> pprint(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, well in fact I need all the links. I will prefer to have the links by state by I didn't find a pattern to relate the links with the states without having in advance the names of the states that are in the page.

So I will try with:

response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul/li').extract()

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez sure, let me help you with grouping the links by state, give me a minute.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez okay, updated with a sample, give it a try and please test if it handles the situations when there are no links for a state. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that's great:

In the case where there aren't links for the mall it return an empty list.

Like in texas.

In the page there is a link for those cases, it have a whole page for the malls of that state
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shopping_malls_in_Texas

But  it's already fine, I have those links in the dictionary could be confusing.